# Telerik MVC Grid Ajax inline editing with automatic focus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

After trying a couple of scenarios, I don't find how to set the focus automatically to the first editable field in the current line.

When you look [in this sample of Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingajax), when you click on the edit button, you then must have to click into the first textbox to edit content.

[image]

Anybody know how to set the focus automatically to the textbox? Is there a built in feature of Telerik to do that?

Note:
If you go to [this sample](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html); a new KendoUI, this is exactly what I want as behavior.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hook into the OnEdit client side event and provide your own function to focus the text field. You may need to play with the jQuery selector some to find what is right for your requirements.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("Grid_onEdit")))

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Grid_onEdit(e)
    {   // focus the first grid element, or the first form element with a validation error
        $("#Grid").find(":input:enabled:visible:first:not(:input[type=submit])").focus();
        $("#Grid").find(".input-validation-error").first().focus();
    }
</script>
```

More on client events [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/clientsideevents)

Comment: Sorry for the long time I took to accept this answer and thank you very much, it works perfectly.